# How to ignore ISoftDelete interface behavior for the related entities queries using EF Core and ABP?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate, ef-core-2.1

I'm using EF Core and ISoftDelete of ABP for some entities. The global version of aspnetcore and EF Core is 2.1. ABP is 3.4.0

For each query to the database (for the ISoftDelete entity) that is not marked by `IgnoreQueryFilters()` ABP is adding to the resulting expression tree (and SQL therefore) something like `where IsDeleted = 0`.
I noticed that it will be also added to the joined table in case of selecting any column of the related entity.
Here are some code samples

```
public class User : EntityBase, ISoftDelete
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class Manager : EntityBase, ISoftDelete
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Here are query without selecting a related entity (User) and the resulting SQL from the profiler

```
var managerIds = _dbContext
    .Set<Manager>()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        ManagerId = x.Id
    })
    .ToArray();
```

```
SELECT [e].[Id] AS [ManagerId]
FROM [Managers] AS [e]
WHERE (([e].[IsDeleted] = 0) OR ([e].[IsDeleted] <> 1))
```

The code that excludes deleted lines was added automatically here and that's expected

Here is the query with a select from a related entity

```
var managerIdsWithUserNames = _dbContext
    .Set<Manager>()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        ManagerId = x.Id,
        UserName = x.User.Name
    })
    .ToArray();
```

```
SELECT [e].[Id] AS [ManagerId], [t].[Name] AS [UserName]
FROM [Managers] AS [e]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [e0].*
    FROM [Users] AS [e0]
    WHERE ([e0].[IsDeleted] = 0) OR ([e0].[IsDeleted] <> 1)
) AS [t] ON [e].[UserId] = [t].[Id]
WHERE (([e].[IsDeleted] = 0) OR ([e].[IsDeleted] <> 1))
```

But in this case, this `where IsDeleted = 0` is added to the joined table and that's not what I expected nor what I needed.

As the result, I need to not exclude deleted Users in a query to the Managers and exclude deleted Managers. I know that I can fix it like this

```
var managerIdsWithUserNames = _dbContext
    .Set<Manager>()
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        ManagerId = x.Id,
        UserName = x.User.Name
    })
    .ToArray();
```

but it doesn't look like a general solution because there could be other related entities in one table.

So is it generally a correct behavior and is there a possibility to disable it for the related entities (extension method probably)?

Please feel free to leave comments and fix grammar.

Comment: Negative. This actually is EF Core global filter behavior, and currently it does not provide fine grained control - it is all or nothing (either ignore or apply all global filters).

Comment: @IvanStoev, so does the EF Core applies this filter to every entity with the IsDeleted column without anything other requirements? Could you leave a link to the corresponding documentation? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Basically the whole [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) documentation topic if you read it carefully.

Comment: You can use IDataFilter to disable ISoftDelete filter for specific portion of your code. Does [this](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.2/Data-Filtering#idatafilter-service-enable-disable-data-filters) meet your requirement?

Comment: @nizoodxs thanks for your answer but we're using another [abp framework](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/).
However, I didn't investigate it much deeper and I ended up admitting that there are no possibilities to do it without ignoring query filters at all

Comment: Fixed the tag [abp] → [aspnetboilerplate].

Comment: Yes, not possible. Related (but different) feature request: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17347. Also see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21459#issuecomment-774363003 ("_My two cents is that the **global query filters** feature should focus on more **global** concerns like these, instead of per-query concerns on IQueryables._"). The way you have fixed it is clean and clear.